# Unable to make 'one-to-one' relationship between the two classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

What shall I do in the following `xml` to make a `one-to-one` relationship between `Country` class and `PM` class ?

```
  <class name="pojo.Country" table="country">
      <id name="c_id">
          <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="name_c" />
      <one-to-one class="pojo.PM" name="name_pm" />
  </class>

  <class name="pojo.PM" table="pm">
      <id name="c_id">
          <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="name_pm"  />
  </class>
```

I am making a one-to-one relation between `name_pm` which is a property defined inside the `PM` class and `name_c` which is a property defined inside `Country` class. The problem occurs when I write :

```
<one-to-one class="pojo.PM" name="name_pm" />
```

It starts to search the property `name_pm` inside the class `PM` when it should search inside the `Country` class.

How do I define a `One-toOne` relation between **name_pm** and **name_c** ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like wrong syntax.

Try

```
<one-to-one name="pmNameInCountryPojo" class="pojo.PM"
            cascade="save-update"></one-to-one>
```

Comment: What will cascade do ? Anyways I am getting the same exception `Could not find a getter for name_pm in class pojo.Country`

Comment: @saplingPro yeah that cascade is optional.

Comment: The error is about the underScore in the varaible name i guess.while its unable to detect the getter.Please change it to namePm and create getter and setter again and try

Comment: No its not the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

The exception itself points to the solution.

You need to create getter and setter for `name_pm` in your `pojo.Country` class.

and add

```
<one-to-one class="pojo.Country" name="${variable-name}" />
```

in your `pojo.PM` configuration and create setter and getter for respective variable in `PM` class.

Look [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example/) example, it will help you.